# Saving form fields into different model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

If I have a model like so:

```
models.py

class SiteMeta(models.Model):
    location_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location, related_name="site")


somewhereelse/models.py

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ward = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

What would be the most efficient way to save name, ward in one ModelForm based on SiteMeta?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass sitemeta as a Foreign key in model Location

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ward = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sitemeta = models.ForeignKey(SiteMeta)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have added `name` and `ward` field in model form of `SiteMeta`.

In that case, you can either define a model form for `Location` and use it to create location object or create `Location` object from fields in `SiteMeta`.
Then save `SiteMeta` object along with setting location.

For example.

```
locationform = LocationForm(request.POST)
if location.is_valid():
    location = locationform.save()
```

OR

```
#validate fields appropriately
location = Location.objects.create(name=request.POST.get('name'),
                                   ward=request.POST.get('ward'), 

sitemetaform = SiteMetaForm(request.POST)
if sitemetaform.is_valid():
    sitemeta = sitemetaform.save(commit=False)
    sitemeta.location = location
    sitemeta.save()
```